# What it "Assets in this source have public URLs" good for?

Tags: assets

just a short question - what is "Assets in this source have public URLs" good for? Oh course, I can't use getUrl() in the templates, yes, but I can still get the filename etc. So I don't see the use of this parameter?

Another question: when I upload assets to craft, sometimes they are put in the folder I expect, sometimes craft creates a subfolder (named like the asset-id I guess) and puts the file inside that folder. In which case a subfolder is created?

Answer (score 1):

It let's you define "private" asset sources that you don't want publicly exposed on the web.

> Another question: when I upload assets to craft, sometimes they are put in the folder I expect, sometimes craft creates a subfolder (named like the asset-id I guess) and puts the file inside that folder.

If you're uploading these files through an [Assets field](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields), then that field's setting can define a [dynamic subfolder path](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths) where the upload will be saved based on the contents of the entry/user/tag/category/etc. that it is being saved in.  Sounds like that's what you've got defined.